# How to add an eventclick on droppable event

Tags: fullcalendar

Might be really simple, but when i drop the droppable event, i want to automatically click on it

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ droppable: true, drop: function(date) { //the command go here! this.click or something like that } });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    $(this).trigger('click');
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log('event clicked');
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ewojadd3/